# Scala: Pattern match on type but exclude specific subtypes?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

For example, if I have a concrete base class and a subclass:

```scala
class A
class B extends A
```

I'm interested in matching on instances of `A` that are NOT also instances of `B`.

The following approaches are possible:

```scala
// Short-circuit
x match {
  case _: B => ()
  case _: A => println("Type A and not B")
  case _ => ()
}
// Using isInstanceOf
x match {
  case a: A if !a.isInstanceOf[B] => println("Type A and not B")
  case _ => ()
}
```

But is there something more idiomatic/succinct/cleaner? Thanks

Comment: Checking for type is already non-idiomatic. And having to exclude one specific subtype usually means a failed abstraction. In any case, the best way would be the first, check first for **B** and then for any other **A**.

Comment: This seem\s a cleatr case for inheritance/overloading rather than pattern matching. Is there some reason you're not doing that?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul yes I'm merely extending an existing open source framework where this type of matching is commonplace. We don't have the flexibility to completely change the design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define custom extractor

```
object ANotB {
  def unapply(a: A): Option[A] = a match {
    case _: B => None
    case _ => Some(a)
  }
}

x match {
  case ANotB(a) => ???
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't specifically mention it in the question, but this approach benefits greatly from being a reusable solution